# How to Serialize a Dictionary<string,string> and not surround the value with quotes?

Tags: json.net

Example model:

```
public class Thing
{
[JsonProperty("foo")]    
public string Foo {get;set;}
[JsonProperty("bars")]  
public Dictionary<string,string> Bars {get;set;}
}
```

i want the output to look like this:

```
{"foo":"Foo Value", "bars":{"key1":key1Value,"key2":key2Value}}
```

The reason I want the values of the Dictionary to be without quotes is so I can pull the value from the client via jquery:

```
{"foo":"Foo Value", "bars":{"key1":$('#key1').val(),"key2":$('#key2').val()}}
```

Is this possible using Json.Net?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question here, the JSON wouldn't be able to be deserialized without the quotes, or do you actually want it serialized as "$('#key1').val()"?

Comment: @PaulTyng, just like I have it above, I need the $('#key1').val() not to be in quotes when it is interpreted by the browser. I am expecting the JQuery selector to pull the value from an element on the page. If it remains in quotes, it is interpreted as a string and the JQuery selector is never run. This would be similar functionality if I were to call a JavaScript function in that section as well.

Comment: [This is similar to what I am looking for.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547550/c-sharp-json-custom-serialization

Comment: Got it, sorry was slow on the response, you got the right answer though, this is the best use case for JSON.NET, any custom serialization stuff like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my implementation I came up with:

```
public class DictionaryConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return objectType == typeof(Dictionary<string, string>);
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            var items = (Dictionary<string, string>)value;
           writer.WriteStartObject();
            foreach (var item in items)
            {

                writer.WritePropertyName(item.Key);
                writer.WriteRawValue(item.Value);

            }
            writer.WriteEndObject();
            writer.Flush();

        }
    }
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404881/custom-conversion-of-specific-objects-in-json-net) helped too.