# Limit the model data fields serialized by Web API based on the return type Interface

Tags: c#, mvvm, asp.net-web-api, json.net

We're updating our architecture to use a single object model for desktop, web and mobile that can be used in the MVVM pattern. I would like to be able to limit the data fields that are serialized through Web API by using interfaces on the controllers. This is required because the model objects for mobile are stored in HTML5 local storage so don't carry optional data while a thin desktop client would be able to store (and work with) more data.

To achieve this a model will implement the different interfaces that define which data fields should be serialized and there will be a controller specific to the interface.

The problem is that the Web API always serializes every field in the model even if it is not part of the interface being returned. How can we only serialize fields in the returned interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this with JsonConverter or using ContractResolver

Create `JsonConverter` and override the `WriteJson` and write your logic to serialise only those data that is needed. Remember to override `CanConvert` and also `CanWrite`.
You can have a look at the link [Custom conversion of specific objects in JSON.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404881/custom-conversion-of-specific-objects-in-json-net) to get an idea

For ContractResolver see the link http://quickduck.com/blog/2011/08/08/overriding-the-default-serialization-behavior-in-json-net/. In this instead of using `base.CreateObjectContract( objectType );` use `new JsonObjectContract( objectType );`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

I have idea how to automate process of serialization of specific interface instead of whole object.
I wrote library having such code inside (for now this piece of code is shared by github gist). It exposes extension method named [ToDynamic](https://gist.github.com/hardhub/7f1fbc1ba236bdf6fbb4/).

```
public static dynamic ToDynamic<T>(this T value, bool deep = true);
```

Use specific T to extract fields available in that T type.
In the following example T will be determined automatically.
So only IClub members will be extracted and serialized:

```
IReadOnlyList<IClub> clubs = retrieving.GetClubs(page, size, criteria);

return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, clubs.Select(item => item.ToDynamic()));
```

Comment: The [ToDynamic](https://gist.github.com/maxim-boligatov/7f1fbc1ba236bdf6fbb4/) link appears to be broken.

Comment: @TroyGizzi I have updated the link (so now it points to the original version). But I am not sure if it is the latest version. A lot of things happened since that moment and a lot of code was reorganized. But let me know if something is wrong and I will come back with latest version or fixed version. Also of course you are free to update it with your own ))

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class that implements just the interface (creating a "viewmodel"), initialize that class with the needed fields and return the object is a solution.

Or if possible, mark the fields private. private fields don't get serialized.
(limiting visibility of fields is always a good thing)

Comment: The ViewModel in this example will be written in TypeScript as it is to run inside the browser on the mobile device. I specifically want a way to return the Model without having to convert it into a new concrete type.