# Creation a custom JSON converter

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm using json.net for experimentation and I'm trying to create a custom converter with that json :

```
{
    "daily" :
    {
        "1388361600000": 2081,
        "1388448000000": 2171,
        "1388534400000": 2244,
        "1388620800000": 2271
    },
    "average":
    {
        "1388361600000": 1923,
        "1388448000000": 1942,
        "1388534400000": 1963,
        "1388620800000": 1984
    }
}
```

the keys are timestamp (they are random)

I am trying to convert to a rootobject auto-created with a Daily class and an Averange Class. I see the ReadJSON and WriteJSON things, but I don't know how to use them for my conversion. I don't want to use the dynamic keyword, I want to make a proper object. So, there's a way to convert that?

Class :

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Daily daily { get; set; }
    public Average average { get; set; }
}

public class Daily
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> dic;
}

public class Average
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> dic;
}
```

Comment: And [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404881/custom-conversion-of-specific-objects-in-json-net?rq=1) did not help you?

Comment: I already checked and no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a converter if you define your `RootObject` class like this:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public Dictionary<string, int> daily { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, int> average { get; set; }
}
```

Would that work for you?