# Json.NET, how to customize serialization to insert a JSON property

Tags: c#, json.net

I have been unable to find a reasonable implementation for `JsonConvert.WriteJson` that allows me to insert a JSON property when serializing specific types.  All my attempts have resulted in "JsonSerializationException : Self referencing loop detected with type XXX".

A little more background on the problem I'm trying to solve: I am using JSON as a config file format, and I'm using a `JsonConverter` to control the type resolution, serialization, and deserialization of my configuration types.  Instead of using the `$type` property, I want to use more meaningful JSON values that are used to resolve the correct types.

In my pared-down example, here's some JSON text:

```
{
  "Target": "B",
  "Id": "foo"
}
```

where the JSON property `"Target": "B"` is used to determine that this object should be serialized into type `B`.  This design might not seem that compelling given the simple example, but it does make the config file format more usable.

I also want the config files to be round-trippable.  I have the deserialize case working, what I can't get working is the serialize case.

The root of my problem is that I can't find an implementation of `JsonConverter.WriteJson` that uses the standard JSON serialization logic, and doesn't throw a "Self referencing loop" exception.  Here's my implementation:

```
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    JProperty typeHintProperty = TypeHintPropertyForType(value.GetType());

    //BUG: JsonSerializationException : Self referencing loop detected with type 'B'. Path ''.
    // Same error occurs whether I use the serializer parameter or a separate serializer.
    JObject jo = JObject.FromObject(value, serializer); 
    if (typeHintProperty != null)
    {
        jo.AddFirst(typeHintProperty);
    }
    writer.WriteToken(jo.CreateReader());
}
```

The seems to me to be a bug in Json.NET, because there should be a way to do this.  Unfortunately all the examples of `JsonConverter.WriteJson` that I've come across (eg [Custom conversion of specific objects in JSON.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404881/custom-conversion-of-specific-objects-in-json-net)) only provide custom serialization of a specific class, using the JsonWriter methods to write out individual objects and properties.

Here's the complete code for an xunit test that exhibits my problem (or [see it here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/b3yrEU) )

```
using System;

using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

using Xunit;


public class A
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public A Child { get; set; }
}

public class B : A {}

public class C : A {}

/// <summary>
/// Shows the problem I'm having serializing classes with Json.
/// </summary>
public sealed class JsonTypeConverterProblem
{
    [Fact]
    public void ShowSerializationBug()
    {
        A a = new B()
              {
                  Id = "foo",
                  Child = new C() { Id = "bar" }
              };

        JsonSerializerSettings jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        jsonSettings.ContractResolver = new TypeHintContractResolver();
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a, Formatting.Indented, jsonSettings);
        Console.WriteLine(json);

        Assert.Contains(@"""Target"": ""B""", json);
        Assert.Contains(@"""Is"": ""C""", json);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void DeserializationWorks()
    {
        string json =
@"{
  ""Target"": ""B"",
  ""Id"": ""foo"",
  ""Child"": { 
        ""Is"": ""C"",
        ""Id"": ""bar"",
    }
}";

        JsonSerializerSettings jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        jsonSettings.ContractResolver = new TypeHintContractResolver();
        A a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<A>(json, jsonSettings);

        Assert.IsType<B>(a);
        Assert.IsType<C>(a.Child);
    }
}

public class TypeHintContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    public override JsonContract ResolveContract(Type type)
    {
        JsonContract contract = base.ResolveContract(type);
        if ((contract is JsonObjectContract)
            && ((type == typeof(A)) || (type == typeof(B))) ) // In the real implementation, this is checking against a registry of types
        {
            contract.Converter = new TypeHintJsonConverter(type);
        }
        return contract;
    }
}


public class TypeHintJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private readonly Type _declaredType;

    public TypeHintJsonConverter(Type declaredType)
    {
        _declaredType = declaredType;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == _declaredType;
    }

    // The real implementation of the next 2 methods uses reflection on concrete types to determine the declaredType hint.
    // TypeFromTypeHint and TypeHintPropertyForType are the inverse of each other.

    private Type TypeFromTypeHint(JObject jo)
    {
        if (new JValue("B").Equals(jo["Target"]))
        {
            return typeof(B);
        }
        else if (new JValue("A").Equals(jo["Hint"]))
        {
            return typeof(A);
        }
        else if (new JValue("C").Equals(jo["Is"]))
        {
            return typeof(C);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Type not recognized from JSON");
        }
    }

    private JProperty TypeHintPropertyForType(Type type)
    {
        if (type == typeof(A))
        {
            return new JProperty("Hint", "A");
        }
        else if (type == typeof(B))
        {
            return new JProperty("Target", "B");
        }
        else if (type == typeof(C))
        {
            return new JProperty("Is", "C");
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (! CanConvert(objectType))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Can't convert declaredType " + objectType + "; expected " + _declaredType);
        }

        // Load JObject from stream.  Turns out we're also called for null arrays of our objects,
        // so handle a null by returning one.
        var jToken = JToken.Load(reader);
        if (jToken.Type == JTokenType.Null)
            return null;
        if (jToken.Type != JTokenType.Object)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Json: expected " + _declaredType + "; got " + jToken.Type);
        }
        JObject jObject = (JObject) jToken;

        // Select the declaredType based on TypeHint
        Type deserializingType = TypeFromTypeHint(jObject);

        var target = Activator.CreateInstance(deserializingType);
        serializer.Populate(jObject.CreateReader(), target);
        return target;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JProperty typeHintProperty = TypeHintPropertyForType(value.GetType());

        //BUG: JsonSerializationException : Self referencing loop detected with type 'B'. Path ''.
        // Same error occurs whether I use the serializer parameter or a separate serializer.
        JObject jo = JObject.FromObject(value, serializer); 
        if (typeHintProperty != null)
        {
            jo.AddFirst(typeHintProperty);
        }
        writer.WriteToken(jo.CreateReader());
    }

}
```

Comment: In your `WriteJson` method in your converter, have you tried removing the `serializer` parameter from the `JObject.FromObject()` call altogether?  Seems to work in [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lZfCWJ)

Comment: Thanks Brian - thank you for looking at this, and you're right, that fixes the Exception.  It doesn't, however solve my problem, because I need to be able to do this in nested objects.  I've updated the example to cover that.  Or, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/b3yrEU (Fiddle is COOL!!)

Comment: I would be interested to learn what you've ended up with. I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 16):

Calling `JObject.FromObject()` from within a converter on the same object being converted will result in a recursive loop, as you have seen.  Normally the solution is to either (a) use a separate JsonSerializer instance inside the converter, or (b) serialize the properties manually, as James pointed out in his answer.  Your case is a little special in that neither of these solutions really work for you: if you use a separate serializer instance that doesn't know about the converter then your child objects will not get their hint properties applied.  And serializing completely manually doesn't work for a generalized solution, as you mentioned in your comments.

Fortunately, there is a middle ground.  You can use a bit of reflection in your `WriteJson` method to get the object properties, then delegate from there to `JToken.FromObject()`.  The converter will be called recursively as it should for the child properties, but not for the current object, so you don't get into trouble.  One caveat with this solution: if you happen to have any `[JsonProperty]` attributes applied to the classes handled by this converter (A, B and C in your example), those attributes will not be respected.

Here is the updated code for the `WriteJson` method:

```
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    JProperty typeHintProperty = TypeHintPropertyForType(value.GetType());

    JObject jo = new JObject();
    if (typeHintProperty != null)
    {
        jo.Add(typeHintProperty);
    }
    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in value.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (prop.CanRead)
        {
            object propValue = prop.GetValue(value);
            if (propValue != null)
            {
                jo.Add(prop.Name, JToken.FromObject(propValue, serializer));
            }
        }
    }
    jo.WriteTo(writer);
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jQrxb8

Answer (score 9):

Example of using a custom converter to take a property we ignore, break it down and add it's properties to it's parent object.:

```
public class ContextBaseSerializer : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(ContextBase).GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var contextBase = value as ContextBase;
        var valueToken = JToken.FromObject(value, new ForcedObjectSerializer());

        if (contextBase.Properties != null)
        {
            var propertiesToken = JToken.FromObject(contextBase.Properties);
            foreach (var property in propertiesToken.Children<JProperty>())
            {
                valueToken[property.Name] = property.Value;
            }
        }

        valueToken.WriteTo(writer);
    }
}
```

We must override the serializer so we can specify a custom resolver:

```
public class ForcedObjectSerializer : JsonSerializer
{
    public ForcedObjectSerializer()
        : base()
    {
        this.ContractResolver = new ForcedObjectResolver();
    }
}
```

And in the custom resolver we'll trash the Converter from the JsonContract, this will force the internal serializers to use the default object serializer:

```
public class ForcedObjectResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    public override JsonContract ResolveContract(Type type)
    {
        // We're going to null the converter to force it to serialize this as a plain object.
        var contract =  base.ResolveContract(type);
        contract.Converter = null;
        return contract;
    }
}
```

That should get you there, or close enough. :) I use this in https://github.com/RoushTech/SegmentDotNet/ which has test cases covering this use case (including nesting our custom serialized class), details on the discussion covering that here: https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/386

Comment: This is easily the most underrated answer here. For what its worth, this wasn't a 100% perfect solution for me, as I really want to use all the settings from the original serializer. [Check out this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38230327/2283050). You may consider refining this answer to reflect the benefits. Still, amazing work.

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
public class TypeHintContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{

  protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type,
      MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
  {
    IList<JsonProperty> result = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);
    if (type == typeof(A))
    {
      result.Add(CreateTypeHintProperty(type,"Hint", "A"));
    }
    else if (type == typeof(B))
    {
      result.Add(CreateTypeHintProperty(type,"Target", "B"));
    }
    else if (type == typeof(C))
    {
      result.Add(CreateTypeHintProperty(type,"Is", "C"));
    }
    return result;
  }

  private JsonProperty CreateTypeHintProperty(Type declaringType, string propertyName, string propertyValue)
  {
    return new JsonProperty
    {
        PropertyType = typeof (string),
        DeclaringType = declaringType,
        PropertyName = propertyName,
        ValueProvider = new TypeHintValueProvider(propertyValue),
        Readable = false,
        Writable = true
    };
  }
}
```

The type value provider required for that can be as simple as this:

```
public class TypeHintValueProvider : IValueProvider
{

  private readonly string _value;
  public TypeHintValueProvider(string value)
  {
    _value = value;
  }

  public void SetValue(object target, object value)
  {        
  }

  public object GetValue(object target)
  {
    return _value;
  }

}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/DRNzz8

Comment: This looks like what Im after, but I want to use it for serializing but I can't get it to work (properties get added but don't appear in json on the browser). Should it work for serializing?

Answer (score 2):

Brian's answer is great and should help the OP, but the answer has a couple of problems that others may run into, namely: 1) an overflow exception gets thrown when serializing array properties, 2) any *static* public properties will be emitted to JSON which you likely don't want.

Here is another version that tackles those problems:

```
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    Type valueType = value.GetType();
    if (valueType.IsArray)
    {
        var jArray = new JArray();
        foreach (var item in (IEnumerable)value)
            jArray.Add(JToken.FromObject(item, serializer));

        jArray.WriteTo(writer);
    }
    else
    {
        JProperty typeHintProperty = TypeHintPropertyForType(value.GetType());

        var jObj = new JObject();
        if (typeHintProperty != null)
            jo.Add(typeHintProperty);

        foreach (PropertyInfo property in valueType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
        {
            if (property.CanRead)
            {
                object propertyValue = property.GetValue(value);
                if (propertyValue != null)
                    jObj.Add(property.Name, JToken.FromObject(propertyValue, serializer));
            }
        }

        jObj.WriteTo(writer);
    }
}
```

Comment: After 2 hours of working on this issue your answer finally saved me, with some adaptations this solved my issue. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Ran into this problem in 2019 :)

The answer is, if you don't want an @stackoverflow Don't Forget to override:

- bool CanWrite
- bool CanRead

  ```
  public class DefaultJsonConverter : JsonConverter
  {
      [ThreadStatic]
      private static bool _isReading;

      [ThreadStatic]
      private static bool _isWriting;

      public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
      {
          try
          {
              _isWriting = true;

              Property typeHintProperty = TypeHintPropertyForType(value.GetType());

              var jObject = JObject.FromObject(value, serializer);
              if (typeHintProperty != null)
              {
                  jObject.AddFirst(typeHintProperty);
              }
              writer.WriteToken(jObject.CreateReader());
          }
          finally
          {
              _isWriting = false;
          }
      }

      public override bool CanWrite
      {
          get
          {
              if (!_isWriting)
                  return true;

              _isWriting = false;

              return false;
          }
      }

      public override bool CanRead
      {
          get
          {
              if (!_isReading)
                  return true;

              _isReading = false;

              return false;
          }
      }

      public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
      {
          return true;
      }

      public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
      {
          try
          {
              _isReading = true;
              return serializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType);
          }
          finally
          {
              _isReading = false;
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Credit to: https://github.com/RicoSuter/NJsonSchema/blob/master/src/NJsonSchema/Converters/JsonInheritanceConverter.cs

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem and here's what I do in the contract resolver

```
if (contract is JsonObjectContract && ShouldUseConverter(type))     
{
    if (contract.Converter is TypeHintJsonConverter)
    {
        contract.Converter = null;
    }
    else
    {
        contract.Converter = new TypeHintJsonConverter(type);
    }
}
```

This was the only way I found to avoid the StackOverflowException. Effectively every other call will not use the converter.

Answer (score 0):

The serializer is calling into your converter which is then calling into the serializer which is calling into your converter, etc.

Either use a new instance of the serializer that doesn't have your converter with JObject.FromObject, or serialize the type's members manually.

Comment: Thanks.  Serializing my type's members manually is not workable, as this is a generalized problem and I need it to work with any configured type.  What I'm looking for is a way to intercept the normal serialization logic to insert the property.  Ideally it would also use any other custom serialization settings in the original serializer, but I can get by without that for now.

I'll try it using a second Serializer and JObject.

Answer (score -2):

After having the same issue, and finding this and other similar questions, I found that the **JsonConverter** has an over-ridable property CanWrite.

Overriding this property to return false fixed this issue for me.

```
public override bool CanWrite
{
    get
    { 
        return false;
    }
}
```

Hopefully, this will help others having the same problem.

Comment: Doing this via slightly modified solution from http://stackoverflow.com/a/9444519/1037948, I started getting `NotImplementedException`s from `WriteJson` recently, and no idea why.  I suspect it's because I also overrode `CanConvert`.  Just wanted to point out.

Comment: If `CanWrite` returns false `WriteJson` is not called at all.