# Copy JsonSerializerSettings from JsonSerializer to new JsonSerializer

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

Is there any way to take the settings out of a `JsonSerializer` class and reimplement them in a new `JsonSerializer`?

There doesn't seem to be any methods to do anything like that. The best I found was a private method to be called through reflection, `ApplySerializerSettings`.

I'm trying to take the serializer from the `WriteJson` method and copy it into a new serializer, tweaking it a bit. Specifically I want to replace the `ContractResolver`.

```
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
```

Answer (score 14):

Seems like the best way is to just copy all the settings into a new object. There are a ton of them, so here's a nice extension method to work with (as of 8.0.3).

```
public static class JsonSerializerExtensions
{
  public static JsonSerializer DeepCopy(this JsonSerializer serializer)
  {
    var copiedSerializer = new JsonSerializer
    {
      Context = serializer.Context,
      Culture = serializer.Culture,
      ContractResolver = serializer.ContractResolver,
      ConstructorHandling = serializer.ConstructorHandling,
      CheckAdditionalContent = serializer.CheckAdditionalContent,
      DateFormatHandling = serializer.DateFormatHandling,
      DateFormatString = serializer.DateFormatString,
      DateParseHandling = serializer.DateParseHandling,
      DateTimeZoneHandling = serializer.DateTimeZoneHandling,
      DefaultValueHandling = serializer.DefaultValueHandling,
      EqualityComparer = serializer.EqualityComparer,
      FloatFormatHandling = serializer.FloatFormatHandling,
      Formatting = serializer.Formatting,
      FloatParseHandling = serializer.FloatParseHandling,
      MaxDepth = serializer.MaxDepth,
      MetadataPropertyHandling = serializer.MetadataPropertyHandling,
      MissingMemberHandling = serializer.MissingMemberHandling,
      NullValueHandling = serializer.NullValueHandling,
      ObjectCreationHandling = serializer.ObjectCreationHandling,
      PreserveReferencesHandling = serializer.PreserveReferencesHandling,
      ReferenceResolver = serializer.ReferenceResolver,
      ReferenceLoopHandling = serializer.ReferenceLoopHandling,
      StringEscapeHandling = serializer.StringEscapeHandling,
      TraceWriter = serializer.TraceWriter,
      TypeNameHandling = serializer.TypeNameHandling,
      SerializationBinder = serializer.SerializationBinder,
      TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling = serializer.TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling
    };
    foreach (var converter in serializer.Converters)
    {
      copiedSerializer.Converters.Add(converter);
    }
    return copiedSerializer;
  }
}
```

It's ugly, but at least you only have to write it once.
Be slightly careful, as the properties themselves are not deep copied.

**Answer below is flaky depending on your implementation**, especially when it comes to resolving a contract. Keeping it in just in case it helps someone.

---

So, I can't quite copy the settings, but I found a good work around that might want to be considered. You can simply set the properties you want to change, in a locked context, and then reset them afterward.

```
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    var thing = value as IThing;

    if (thing == null)
        throw new ArgumentException($"Writing Json failed because " + 
          "value was not a 'Thing' of type, {typeof(IThing).FullName}");

    JObject jsonThing;
    //If your solution is multithreaded,
    //and is using a shared serializer (which you probably are),
    //you should lock the serializer so that it doesn't accidentally use 
    //the "CustomObjectResolver"
    lock (serializer)
    {
        //Hold the original value(s) to reset later
        var originalContractResolver = serializer.ContractResolver;
        //Set custom value(s)
        serializer.ContractResolver = new CustomObjectResolver();
        //Serialization with custom properties
        jsonThing = JObject.FromObject(value, serializer);
        //Reset original value(s)
        serializer.ContractResolver = originalContractResolver;
    }

    //Finish serializing and write to writer.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, saves me typing it out! Bit gross that we have to do this though, there really should be something built into Newtonsoft.Json

Answer (score 11):

Not sure if this is on-topic - but as this was the first post that came up when searching for *Clone JSONSerializerSettings* in my Google, I thought I would leave a notice.

I have just had a somewhat similar requirement.

In my .Net Core WebApi solution we have a default for serializing the JSON, with

```
jsonSerializaerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
```

But in a few endpoints I would like to serialize null properties as well, as these endpoints represent a dataset. So all objects should have all properties when serialized.

I've tried a few approaches, and then reading up on Options pattern, I stumbled upon IOptionSnapshot - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.1#reload-configuration-data-with-ioptionssnapshot

So I ended up getting an IOptionsSnapshot injected into my controller method, and this gives me a copy of the default options, which I can modify and use for this single request.

And on next request, injected options are back to default.

Nice and easy - at least for my purpose.

So a final solution for my sample is like this

```
[HttpPost("dataset", Name = "GetReportDataset")]
public IActionResult GetReportDataset(
    [FromServices]IOptionsSnapshot<MvcJsonOptions> jsonOptions,
    [FromBody]DataSetReport report,
    [FromQuery]int? top)
{
    //Logic to fetch dataset
    var myDataSet = myRepository.GetDataset(report, top);

    var serializerSettings = jsonOptions.Value.SerializerSettings;
    serializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include;

    return new JsonResult(myDataSet, serializerSettings);
}
```

Hope this helps someone else coming here for similar usage.

/Anders

Comment: For .NET Core this should be the answer. I ran into the same exact scenario where 99% of the serialization happens with the default settings but there is one endpoint which I want to have a single different option.

Comment: Yep, it works. Btw they added a copy ctor https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30445

Comment: But the original question was about `Newtonsoft.Json` what you describe is a solution for `System.Text.Json`