# Custom serializer for just one property in Json.NET, without changing the model class

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I need to do something like the following, but I need to do it without putting an attribute on or otherwise polluting the model class. An ideal solution would work via the `JsonSerializerSettings`, without disturbing other custom serialization. Incidentally, the below came from this question: [Custom conversion of specific objects in JSON.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404881/custom-conversion-of-specific-objects-in-json-net?rq=1)

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(AllCapsConverter))]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    // more properties here in the real example, some of which nest to properties that use their own JsonConverters.
}
```

The `JsonConverter` for this toy example (content is not really relevant; what is relevant is that I use it for the property):

```
public class AllCapsConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        => objectType == typeof(string);

    public override bool CanRead => false;

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var str = value as string;
        var upper = str.ToUpperInvariant();
        JToken j = JToken.FromObject(upper);
        j.WriteTo(writer);
    }
}
```

A passing unit test:

```
public class PersonSerializationTest
{
    [Fact]
    public void SerializePerson_LastNameCaps()
    {
        var person = new Person
        {
            FirstName = "George",
            LastName = "Washington"
        };
        var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person);
        var expected = @"{""FirstName"":""George"",""LastName"":""WASHINGTON""}";
        Assert.Equal(expected, serialized);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can programmatically apply a `JsonConverter` to one or more properties in a model class without using attributes via a custom `ContractResolver`.  Here is a dirt simple example, which applies your `AllCapsConverter` to the `LastName` property in your `Person` class.  (If you're looking for a more robust solution, have a look at @dbc's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53768445/10263).  My intent here was to show the simplest example that could possibly work.)

```
public class CustomResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        JsonProperty prop = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        if (prop.DeclaringType == typeof(Person) && prop.UnderlyingName == "LastName")
        {
            prop.Converter = new AllCapsConverter();
        }
        return prop;
    }
}
```

Here is the updated test and `Person` model which shows how to use the resolver:

```
public class PersonSerializationTest
{
    [Fact]
    public void SerializePerson_LastNameCaps()
    {
        var person = new Person
        {
            FirstName = "George",
            LastName = "Washington"
        };
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = new CustomResolver()
        };
        var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person, settings);
        var expected = @"{""FirstName"":""George"",""LastName"":""WASHINGTON""}";
        Assert.Equal(expected, serialized);
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/o4e3WP

Answer (score 1):

You can apply converters to specific properties by using a [custom `IContractResolver`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm#CustomIContractResolverExamples) inheriting from `DefaultContractResolver`.

First, grab `ConfigurableContractResolver` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46083201/3744182) to *[How to add metadata to describe which properties are dates in JSON.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46047308/3744182)*:

```
public class ConfigurableContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    // This contract resolver taken from the answer to
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46047308/how-to-add-metadata-to-describe-which-properties-are-dates-in-json-net
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/46083201/3744182

    readonly object contractCreatedPadlock = new object();
    event EventHandler<ContractCreatedEventArgs> contractCreated;
    int contractCount = 0;

    void OnContractCreated(JsonContract contract, Type objectType)
    {
        EventHandler<ContractCreatedEventArgs> created;
        lock (contractCreatedPadlock)
        {
            contractCount++;
            created = contractCreated;
        }
        if (created != null)
        {
            created(this, new ContractCreatedEventArgs(contract, objectType));
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler<ContractCreatedEventArgs> ContractCreated
    {
        add
        {
            lock (contractCreatedPadlock)
            {
                if (contractCount > 0)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("ContractCreated events cannot be added after the first contract is generated.");
                }
                contractCreated += value;
            }
        }
        remove
        {
            lock (contractCreatedPadlock)
            {
                if (contractCount > 0)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("ContractCreated events cannot be removed after the first contract is generated.");
                }
                contractCreated -= value;
            }
        }
    }

    protected override JsonContract CreateContract(Type objectType)
    {
        var contract = base.CreateContract(objectType);
        OnContractCreated(contract, objectType);
        return contract;
    }
}

public class ContractCreatedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public JsonContract Contract { get; private set; }
    public Type ObjectType { get; private set; }

    public ContractCreatedEventArgs(JsonContract contract, Type objectType)
    {
        this.Contract = contract;
        this.ObjectType = objectType;
    }
}

public static class ConfigurableContractResolverExtensions
{
    public static ConfigurableContractResolver Configure(this ConfigurableContractResolver resolver, EventHandler<ContractCreatedEventArgs> handler)
    {
        if (resolver == null || handler == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        resolver.ContractCreated += handler;
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

Then, create a method to configure the `JsonObjectContract` for `Person` as follows:

```
public static class JsonContractExtensions
{
    public static void ConfigurePerson(this JsonContract contract)
    {
        if (!typeof(Person).IsAssignableFrom(contract.UnderlyingType))
            return;
        var objectContract = contract as JsonObjectContract;
        if (objectContract == null)
            return;
        var property = objectContract.Properties.Where(p => p.UnderlyingName == nameof(Person.LastName)).Single();
        property.Converter = new AllCapsConverter();
    }
}
```

And finally serialize as follows:

```
// Cache the contract resolver statically for best performance.
var resolver = new ConfigurableContractResolver()
    .Configure((s, e) => { e.Contract.ConfigurePerson(); });

var settigs = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = resolver,
};

var person = new Person
{
    FirstName = "George",
    LastName = "Washington"
};
var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person, settigs);
```

Notes:

- Rather than creating `ConfigurableContractResolver` it would have been possible to subclass `DefaultContractResolver`, override [`DefaultContractResolver.CreateProperty`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver_CreateProperty.htm), and hardcode the necessary logic for `Person.LastName` there.  Creating a configurable resolver that allows for customizations to be combined in run time seems more useful and reuseable, however.
- In `AllCapsConverter.WriteJson()` it would be simpler to use [`writer.WriteValue(string)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonWriter_WriteValue_32.htm) to write your uppercase string:

  ```
  public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
  {
      var upper = ((string)value).ToUpperInvariant();
      writer.WriteValue(upper);
  }
  ```
- You may want to [cache the contract resolver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33557737) for best performance.

Sample fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hx3R73).